# Women's hair tying during puja

Tags: puja

I heard someone say that women should not have hair open during shubha karyas, and have open (untied) hair during pitru karyas.

In South India we are thus normally following but in North women normally don't tie hair at all.

I was told Draupadi as example... keeping her hair untied, which wasn't normal.

Is there any script which supports this rule?

Comment: @sv. There is answers but without much of references.

Comment: Ok but it's still seems like a duplicate of the other question.